# When should a transponder be used?

Tags: avionics, transponder, aircraft-operations

When should a transponder be turned turn on?

1. On the ground?
2. Always in flight?
3. Only when required: during radar service (flight following), above 10,000ft MSL, inside the Mode C Veil, or on IFR flight?

Should Altitude Mode be used whenever the transpoder is on?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At least in the United States the FAA recently (I *think* in 2012?) changed the recommendation for transponder operation in the AIM.  It now reads:

> Civil and military transponders should be turned to the “on" or normal altitude reporting position prior to moving on the airport surface to ensure the aircraft is visible to ATC surveillance systems. IN ALL CASES, WHILE IN CONTROLLED AIRSPACE EACH PILOT OPERATING AN AIRCRAFT EQUIPPED WITH AN OPERABLE ATC TRANSPONDER MAINTAINED IN ACCORDANCE WITH 14 CFR SECTION 91.413 MUST OPERATE THE TRANSPONDER, INCLUDING MODE C IF INSTALLED, ON THE APPROPRIATE CODE OR AS ASSIGNED BY ATC. IN CLASS G AIRSPACE, THE TRANSPONDER SHOULD BE OPERATING WHILE AIRBORNE UNLESS OTHERWISE REQUESTED BY ATC.

(Cribbed from [Chapter 4-1 of the AIM](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/))

So, basically "Turn it on before you taxi, and turn it off right before you shut down the engine. Always use the Altitude mode (Mode C) unless ATC tells you otherwise."

---

In practice having the transponder on while on the airport surface doesn't do much unless your field has something like [ASDE-X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASDE-X) which plots aircraft transponders on a screen in the tower, but it generally doesn't hurt anything and it ensures you don't forget to turn the transponder on when you take off.

Operating your transponder while on the ground *may* cause "ground clutter" on nearby radar station's displays (possibly setting off the conflict-alert system) - this is why many of us were taught to set our transponders to standby mode while on the ground. In practice this usually isn't an issue, and if it is a problem local ATC will ask you to "*squawk standby while taxiing*" to resolve the issue.
If anyone gives you a hard time about it copy the number and politely quote the AIM.

Comment: the other reason why we were taught to turn the xponder off on the ground is because older transponders had a cavity magnetron, which is a kind of high-voltage tube. The idea was to turn them off when not in use, to prevent them from wearing out, and to reduce the load on the electrical systems in old airplanes

Comment: @rbp the standby mode runs the cavity tube heater (at least it does in the AT-150 I have), it just doesn't connect it to transmit replies when the transponder gets interrogated. Whether you do more damage cycling the heater on & off or letting it run all the time is debatable, but turning it off on your taxi back to the ramp does take about an amp off the electrical load which is something if your electrical system is marginal at low RPM.

Comment: If the above quotation is from the AIM, then it is recommended, not required (as you've noted). Note: I'm not asserting that it's not good practice to use ALT reporting when taxiing! Is there a FAR # that mandates any transponder use outside class A, C and the class B 30NM veil?

Comment: @CJBS [FAR 91.215](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=14:2.0.1.3.10#se14.2.91_1215) would be the base regulation: Paragraph C says: *While in the airspace as specified in paragraph (b) of this section **or in all controlled airspace**, each person operating an aircraft equipped with an operable ATC transponder maintained in accordance with §91.413 of this part shall operate the transponder, including Mode C equipment if installed, and shall reply on the appropriate code or as assigned by ATC.* (Bolding mine - "required everywhere except Class G airspace" is my read of that regulation.)

Comment: @voretaq7 Thanks - good reference. I'm assuming 'airspace' doesn't include taxiing on the ramp or even taxiways (per the FAR), given that the ground isn't controlled airspace.

Comment: @CJBS As far as I can tell it's not a *regulatory* requirement on the ground (at least under Part 91 - Parts 121 & 135 may impose additional requirements). At larger airports with [ground surveillance radar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASDE-X) it may be an *operational* requirement though (i.e. ATC will ask you to turn on your transponder so they can see you on their displays).

Comment: In the past it was recommended to turn off the transponder on the ground. I believe this was because a bunch of planes on the ground would show up on controllers' displays and make it hard to see the airborne planes. Now, filtering makes that a non-issue, and they recommend transponders on the ground so planes can be tracked for tower/ground controllers.

Comment: I'd like to add that it also allows ATC to verify mode C readout by comparing against field elevation. So they don't have to ask "Say altitude passing"

Answer (score 1):

For aircraft equipped with ADS-B Out, the following regulation applies (emphasis mine)

> 14 CFR 91.225(f)Each person operating an aircraft equipped with ADS-B Out must operate this equipment in the transmit mode **at all times**

This a nuance to the ADS-B regulations that many may miss. So, for ADS-B it is required to be on (ALT) even while on the ground.